# How to change a specific line color on console? When Coding in C using latest IDE's. If I use system("color ") than whole foreground color change

Tags: c++, c

```
 This code is used to select menu options using the up & down arrow 
key but I want the output line in the arrowhere function as coloured
and output lines in menu function should be different in colour
on Console as compared to the line of function arrowhere
      void menu()
            {
                system("cls");
                int position = 1;
                int keypress = 0;
                while (keypress != 13) Counter Char Key Enter Is Set
                {
                    system("cls");
                    arrowhere(1, position);
                    printf("Addition\n"); Its color will be remain default such that white
                    arrowhere(2, position);
                    printf("Subtraction\n"); Its color will be remain default such that white
        
                    arrowhere(3, position);
                    printf("Exit\n"); Its color will be remain default such that white
        
                    keypress = getch();
                    if (keypress == 80 && position != MAX) To check down key 
                    {
                        position++;
                    }
                    else if (keypress == 72 && position != MIN)To Check Upper Key
                    {
                        position--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        position = position;If any other key except Enter is pressed than position is not affected
                    }
                }
            }
```

void arrowhere(int realposition, int arrowposition)   Output arrow position adjacent to the list present in Menu function.

```
        {
            if (realposition == arrowposition)
            {
```

printf("--->> - "); I want to change only this line colour such that blue, This arrow appears adjacent to the menu options see Menu() function.
}

```
        }
```

Comment: It really depends on the terminal/console attached to your output stream. Looks like you are using a DOS or Windows console. If it's pure old DOS, or  a new enough Win10 console, it may support some [ANSI control codes](https://www.google.com/search?q=ANSI+control+codes).

Comment: No, I am using Win10 Console & IDE's are VS Code and Code blocks.  Everything is Up to date on my computer Thanks

Comment: Then you should be able to use the ANSI control codes embedded in your output strings. You change the foreground/background color of individual characters if you like. You can also control whether or not they are bold.

Comment: Use the Windows [console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) functions such as [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute).

Comment: Thanks Quite long material to study. Thank you very much

Comment: What about IDEs like Emacs, Netbeans, Visual Studio Code and others?  Aren't they the latest too?

Comment: If you are programming in C (like your question says), why the C++ tag?  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::map` which you can use to associate keypresses with ANSI Escape Sequences.  The C language doesn't have `std::map`.